# why we cannot write constants and if else logic in javascript class?

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-class

The question is too simplistic but it tries to understand the core concept of class in javascript
I would like someone to explain why following are not a valid code?

```
class One {const d = 1;}

class Second { 
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('key') == 'value')
    {
     state = 'value'
    }
}
```

Comment: (most) statements are not valid in a `class`. That's not really restricted to JavaScript, though - you similarly cannot write an `if` freely within the body of a class in Java. Pretty sure you can't do it in C#, either. What *should* an `if` do, anyway? Set it up once statically or do a per-instance initialisation? If it's per-instance we *already* have a mechanism for that - the constructor.

Comment: Can you write constants and if else logic inside javaScript Object?

Comment: Class actually provides us an abstraction.

Comment: Thank you for comments, basically the question is inspired by thought that class is a syntactic sugar over javascript functions for inheritance

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain in that context, then can you do `One.prototype.const d = 1`?

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain You can put that code inside the `constructor` if that is what you meant to do.

Comment: yes, I did write that, now I want someone to come and explain class in a way that would have everyone understood it to the core